# Problems in ssh to vm in google cloud

Tags: ssh, putty, google-compute-engine

Hi Ive just started using google cloud and i was following the tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxZvofAvgHQ#t=40

and i was stuck at around 4.18 where i cant ssh as when i pasted my `gcutil --service_version="v1" --project="stone-ground-609" ssh --zone="us-central1-a" "instance-1"`

it gave me the error [image: putty fatal error]

can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use putty you need to setup you ssh keys. You can follow the steps mentioned in the following link to setup Putty.
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/console#start

Answer (score 0):

You will have to generate an SSH key to authorize your computer to connect to your server

- SSH keys come in 2 parts

  1. The public key
  2. Your private key

Think of public as a lock and the private key is the key that only you have to open that lock.

If there are others who need access to your server, each of those users and machines should get their own SSH keys.

To create the SSH Key pair, the steps to do that are different if you are on Mac or Linux compared to Windows.

## Windows: Download PuTTY

### Create the SSH Key: open the application PuTTYgen

- Click start
- Create randomness, by moving your mouse
- For the key comment type in the username of your VM
- Click Save Private Key (end the file name in .ppk)
- Click Save Public Key (end the file name in .pub)
- Upload the Public Key to your VM by chosing in in the Google Cloud Console and clicking "Edit VM"

### Connect via SSH: Open Putty

1. In Host Name type in your Google VM's IP Address
2. In the left hand navigation bar choose 'Connection' -> 'SSH' -> 'Auth'
3. Under "Private key file for authentication:" Click Browse and locate your private key
4. Under 'Connection' -> 'Data' Type in the VM username in "Auto-login username"
5. Click back to ‘Session’
6. Save the settings
7. Click 'Open'

## Mac: Open the Terminal

### Create the SSH Key

Type in `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/{filename} -C {username}`

Upload the Public Key to your VM

1. In the terminal type `cat ~/.ssh/{filename}`
2. Back in Google Cloud's Console: Click on your instance name
3. Click 'Edit'
4. Scroll down to 'SSH'
5. Paste
6. Save

### Connect via the Terminal

Type in `ssh -i ~/.ssh/{private-key} {username}@{ip-address}`

Hit enter